# Character Encoding Conversion In Groovy From UTF-8 to EUC-JP

Tags: java, groovy, utf-8, character-encoding, cjk

We require character encoding conversion for one of our service, our requirement is to fetch characters in UTF-8 encoded format and should convert to EUC-JP then prepare some hashing on (Groovy based on) jdk8.

In php, similar solution works fine for us and coded as,

```
$encodedToEucJp = mb_convert_encoding($inputStringWithUtf8, “EUC-JP”);
Print_r(md5($encodedToEucJp));
```

We have tried many ways for the solution, e.g.,

```
Java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance(‘MD5’)
.digest(New String(inputStringWithUtf8.getBytes(“UTF-8”), “EUC-JP”)
.getBytes(“EUC-JP”))
.encodeHex()
.toString();
```

But, this solution failed for some of the characters that produces different digest then from our php coded solution. Here few characters are mentioned ―, ĭ, ? etc. That’s the reason why we couldn't product same digest with same input both in php and java system.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this part of the code:

```
New String(inputStringWithUtf8.getBytes(“UTF-8”), “EUC-JP”)
```

Basically, you try to interpret an UTF-8 byte array as if it were encoded in EUC-JP, which is a non-sense.

The following code should do the job

```
    Java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance(‘MD5’)
            .digest(inputStringWithUtf8.getBytes(“EUC-JP”))
            .encodeHex()
            .toString();
```